# How to create a dummy http request and response object in Node for unit testing

Tags: node.js

I need to test a function which is called by my `node` application receives an `http` request from client.

```
var indexExports = module.exports = {
  
  homepageHandler: function (req, res) {
    console.log(`index page. Req ${req}`);
    return res.status(200).json({
      "message": "welcome"
    });;
  }
}
```

I want to `unit test` it. I have created a test in `jest`. However, I don't know how to pass a dummy `http` request to the function.

```
describe("Endpoints are accessible", () => {
    it("GET request for homepage should return 200", async () => {
      const baseURL = process.env.EXPRESS_SERVER_TEST 
      console.log(`base url is ${baseURL}`);
      indexControllerModule.indexExports.homepageHandler(req,res) //HOW TO CREATE req and res?
      .then((result)=>{
        //TBD
      })
      .catch((error)=>{
        console.log(`error in accessing homepage: ${error}`);
      })
    });  
});
```

Comment: Consider using [`supertest` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) to test an HTTP server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious way would be to create the `req`, and `res` objects from scratch judging by how they are used:

```
const mockReq = {
  // req doesn't seem to be used
}
```

```
const mockRes = {
  status: jest.fn(),
  json: jest.fn(),
}

mockRes.status.mockReturnValue(mockRes)
```

```
.homepageHandler(mockReq, mockRes)
```